# Whether I can use ipmitool in the VM?

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, module

When I start the `ipmi_si` module:

```
modprobe ipmi_si
```

there gets error:

> FATAL: Error inserting ipmi_si (/lib/modules/2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/char/ipmi/ipmi_si.

My environment is a Virtual Machine `CentOS 6.9`.

I found some speech says this because of its a VM, not a physical machine.

So, I want to know whether I can use ipmitool in the VM?

Comment: ipmitool talks to the bmc (board management controller). This is a different cpu than the main cpu. If you are trying to talk to the bmc associated with your VM, we need to know if your VM emulates this additional cpu. Of course if you have more than one machine ipmitool can talk to the bmc of a different machine.

Comment: I've used this in test environments. Kind of kludgy but if you to control KVM VMs with ipmitool, it seems to be the only method: https://github.com/openstack/virtualbmc